# Android fingerprint support: How safe is storing TOTP secret in Android keystore using fingerprint data?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

The title says it all.

I would like to add fingerprint support to an app (and skip SMS **authentication**) and I was thinking of storing users' TOTP secret to their device's keystore and sealing it with their fingerprint data upon setup.

How safe is this or what's the best way to integrate fingerprint authentication?

Answer (score 0):

This doc will show you how to implement biometric authentication:
https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth

And here's an article on using Keystore and fingerprint API:
https://medium.com/beautycoder/android-security-and-fingerprint-ef0f6f344888